# angularjs getting ng-options obj id instead of value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
      <select ng-model="ad.Categorie"
              ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in categories"
              ng-change="getSubcategories()"
              class="form-control"
              ng-required="true"
              name="categorie">
        <option value="">--  --</option>
      </select>
```

When i submit getting ng-options array index instead of ad.Categorie value and i solved with hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="categorie" value="@{{ad.Categorie}}" />
```

but it seems wrong solution any idea?

```
var categories = [{"id":1,"name":"cat1"},{"id":2,"name":"cat2"}];
```

reading from database. I want categories id as fk

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $ad = new Ad;
    $ad->categorie_id= $request->categorie;
    $ad->subcategorie_id= $request->subcategorie;
    $ad->type_id= $request->type;
    $ad->location_id= $request->location;
    $ad->title= $request->title;
    $ad->description= $request->description;
    $ad->price= $request->price;
    $ad->phone= $request->phone;
    $ad->code= $request->code;
    //$ad->img = $request->file('img');
    //$files = $request->file('img');
    $ad->save();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

is this array $request->categorie that's why i get index?

Comment: can you supply the json for `categories`. Also you appear to have a typo in your select (no closing `"` after the `name` attribute)

Comment: var categories = [{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}] reading from database yeah that " was correct in code

Comment: `ng-options="obj.name for obj in categories"` doesnt work?

Comment: if you're looking for the way to get the `id` of the item you've selected (_I want categories id_), your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/va6p6y4u/

Comment: Yes it is already working for `id`, I am not sure what he is looking for, it is not clear. so I am assuming he needs object not `id`

Comment: are you confused ? just use ng-options="obj.name for obj in categories"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already getting right `id`, I am assuming you want to get object or index. this code is for getting index, id and object:

```
   <select ng-model="ad.Categorie" 
    ng-options="obj.name for obj in categories" 
    ng-change="getSubcategories()" 
    class="form-control" 
    ng-required="true" 
    name="categorie">
   </select>
```

In your controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.categories = [{
    "id": 11,
    "name": "name1"
  }, {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "name2"
  }];
  $scope.ad = {}
  $scope.getSubcategories = function() {
    console.log("selected object= ", $scope.ad.Categorie);
    console.log("selected index= ", $scope.categories.indexOf($scope.ad.Categorie));
    console.log("selected id= ",$scope.ad.Categorie.id);
  }
}
```

Here is the working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/30048/

Comment: thanks for answer {"id":1,"name":"Ажлын зар"} still getting as object

Comment: yeah i want get id as foreign key when submit in this case getting array index starting from 0 not id

Comment: yeah that's why i use hidden input ad.Categorie getting correct value but when submit $ad->categorie_id= $request->categorie; i'm getting wrong array index :)

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont understand your issue. what index?

Comment: My problem is saving that index instead of id i think problem is $ad->categorie_id= $request->categorie; or angular name="categorie"  passing index to $request->categorie. Thanks answered well